# $k$ socks $n$ drawers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Consider the following problem:

There are $k$ socks and $n$ drawers which can only contain 1 sock (very small drawer indeed). The drawers are aligned. You put socks in the drawers with uniform probability. You are wondering the law of probability of the number of drawers containing 1 sock and the drawer to its right have also a sock in it.

More formally, write $[1:n]=[1;n]\cap\mathbb{N}$, and let $\eta$ be a configuration of the sock & drawer, meaning $\eta = (\eta_{i})_{i\in [1:n]}\in \Omega=\{0;1\}^{[1:n]}$ where $\eta_{i}=1$ means that there is a sock in the drawer $i$. Furthermore, denote $\mathbb{P}$ the law of probabilty over $\Omega$ such that  $\forall \eta,\sigma \in \Omega:\mathbb{P}(\eta)=\mathbb{P}(\sigma)$

We are looking at the law of probability of the following random variable : $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \eta_i \eta_{i+1} $$ under the condition $\sum \eta_i=k$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $w$ for empty drawers and $z$ for non-empty ones and $u$ for non-empty
drawers with a non-empty drawer  to the right we obtain the generating
function

$$(1+w+w^2+\cdots)
\\ \times \sum_{q\ge 0} (z+z^2u+z^3u^2+\cdots)^q (w+w^2+w^3+\cdots)^q
\\ \times (1+z+z^2u+z^3u^2+\cdots).$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{1-w} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} z^q \frac{1}{(1-uz)^q} w^q \frac{1}{(1-w)^q}
\\ \times \left(1+ z\frac{1}{1-uz}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-w}
\frac{1}{1-wz/(1-w)/(1-uz)} \frac{1+z-uz}{1-uz}
\\ = \frac{1+z-uz}{(1-w)(1-uz)-wz}.$$

Observe that when we put $u=1$ and $w=z$ we obtain

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2-z^2} = \frac{1}{1-2z}$$

which is  a useful sanity check  and shows that we  have accounted for
all strings. Differentiate with respect  to $u$ and set $u=1$ to count
non-empty neighbors:

$$\left.\left(\frac{1+z-uz}{1-w-uz+uwz-wz}\right)'\right|_{u=1}
\\ = \left.-\frac{z}{1-w-uz+uwz-wz}
- \frac{1+z-uz}{(1-w-uz+uwz-wz)^2} (wz-z)\right|_{u=1}
\\ = -\frac{z}{1-w-z} - \frac{1}{(1-w-z)^2}(wz-z)
= \frac{z^2}{(1-w-z)^2}.$$

We thus require

$$[z^k] [w^{n-k}] \frac{z^2}{(1-w-z)^2}$$

where  we may  assume that  $k\ge  2$ since  with $k=1$  or $k=0$  the
expectation is zero. We get

$$[z^{k-2}] [w^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-w-z)^2}
\\ = [z^{k-2}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} [w^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-w/(1-z))^2}
\\ = [z^{k-2}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} (n-k+1) \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-k}}
\\ = (n-k+1) [z^{k-2}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-k+2}}
\\ = (n-k+1) {k-2+n-k+1\choose n-k+1}
\\ = (n-k+1) {n-1\choose n-k+1}
= (n-1) {n-2\choose n-k}.$$

We get for the expectation

$$(n-1)  {n\choose k}^{-1} {n-2\choose n-k} = 
(n-1) \frac{k! (n-k)!}{n!} \frac{(n-2)!}{(k-2)! (n-k)!}$$

which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n} k(k-1).}$$

An elementary immediate  proof is sure to appear  given the simplicity
of this result now that it has been computed.

The interpretation of the question that was used here is documented
in the following Maple code.

```
with(combinat);

EN :=
proc(n, k)
    local choice, res, nb, pos;

    res := 0;

    for choice in choose(n, k) do
        nb := 0;

        for pos to k-1 do
            if choice[pos] + 1 = choice[pos+1] then
                nb := nb+1;
            fi;
        od;

        res := res + nb;
    od;

    res;
end;

F :=
(n,k) ->
coeftayl(coeftayl(z^2/(1-w-z)^2, w=0, n-k), z=0, k);


ENX := (n,k) -> EN(n,k)/binomial(n,k);

FX := (n,k) -> 1/n*k*(k-1);
```

**Addendum.** As an additional sanity check observe that

$$[z^k] [w^{n-k}] 
\left.\frac{1+z-uz}{(1-w)(1-uz)-wz}\right|_{u=1}
\\ = [z^k] [w^{n-k}] 
\frac{1}{(1-w)(1-z)-wz}
= [z^k] [w^{n-k}] \frac{1}{1-w-z}
\\ = [z^k] \frac{1}{1-z} [w^{n-k}] \frac{1}{1-w/(1-z)}
\\ = [z^k] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-k}}
= [z^k] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-k+1}}
\\ = {k+n-k\choose n-k} = {n\choose n-k} = {n\choose k}$$

which is the correct result.

**Remark Nov 9 2016.** Brian Scott asks about the value of

$$[u^m] [z^k] [w^{n-k}] \frac{1+z-uz}{(1-w)(1-uz)-wz}.$$

This is

$$[u^m] [z^k] [w^{n-k}] \frac{1+z-uz}{1-uz-w(1+z-uz)}
\\ = [u^m] [z^k] \frac{1}{1-uz}
[w^{n-k}] \frac{1+z-uz}{1-w(1+z-uz)/(1-uz)}
\\ = [u^m] [z^k] \frac{(1+z-uz)^{n-k+1}}{(1-uz)^{n-k+1}}
\\ = [u^m] [z^k] \left(1+\frac{z}{1-uz}\right)^{n-k+1}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$\sum_{p=0}^{n-k+1} {n-k+1\choose p} [u^m] [z^k]
\frac{z^p}{(1-uz)^p}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{k} {n-k+1\choose p} [u^m]
[z^{k-p}] \frac{1}{(1-uz)^p}.$$

We must have $m=k-p$ or $p=k-m$ and get

$${n-k+1\choose k-m} {m+k-m-1\choose k-m-1}
\\ = {n-k+1\choose k-m} {k-1\choose m}.$$

*We  can compute  higher moments  with  these data.*  We already  have
$\mathrm{E}[X]$ and obtain for $\mathrm{E}[X(X-1)]$

$$\sum_{m=2}^{k-1} m(m-1) {n-k+1\choose k-m} {k-1\choose m}.$$

This is  zero when $k=1$ or  $k=2$ so we  may assume that $k\ge  3$ in
calculating the sum.

$$\sum_{m=2}^{k-1} m(m-1) {n-k+1\choose k-m} \frac{(k-1)(k-2)}{m(m-1)} 
{k-3\choose m-2}
\\ = (k-1)(k-2) \sum_{m=2}^{k-1} {n-k+1\choose k-m} {k-3\choose m-2}
\\ = (k-1)(k-2) \sum_{m=1}^{k-2} {n-k+1\choose m} {k-3\choose k-m-2}.$$

We evaluate this using the Egorychev method and put

$${k-3\choose k-m-2} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k-m-1}} (1+z)^{k-3} \; dz.$$

Observe that this vanishes when $m\ge k-1$ and when $m=0$ where we get
$[z^{k-2}] (1+z)^{k-3}=0$ and  hence we may set the range  of $m$ from
zero to infinity, getting for the sum

$$(k-1)(k-2) \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k-1}} (1+z)^{k-3}
\sum_{m\ge 0} {n-k+1\choose m} z^m 
 \; dz
\\ = (k-1)(k-2) \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k-1}} (1+z)^{n-2}
 \; dz
\\ = (k-1)(k-2) \times {n-2\choose k-2}.$$

We get for the second factorial moment

$$(k-1)(k-2) {n\choose k}^{-1} {n-2\choose k-2}
\\ = (k-1)(k-2) \frac{k! (n-k)!}{n!} \frac{(n-2)!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}.$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1} k(k-1)^2(k-2).$$

We have for the variance

$$\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{E}[X^2]-\mathrm{E}[X]^2
= \mathrm{E}[X(X-1)] + \mathrm{E}[X]  -\mathrm{E}[X]^2$$

so that in the present case we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1} k(k-1)^2(k-2)
+ \frac{1}{n} k(k-1) - \frac{1}{n^2} k^2(k-1)^2.}$$

This simplifies to

$$\frac{k(k-1)(n-k)(n+1-k)}{n^2(n-1)}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The way of computing the generating function is instructive and natural.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Nice presentation! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $B(n,k)$ be the set of $n$-bit strings with exactly $k$ ones. For $b=b_1b_2\ldots b_n\in B(n,k)$ let

$$f(b)=|\{i\in[n-1]:b_i=b_{i+1}=1\}|\;;$$

if all we want is the expected value of $f(b)$ when $b$ is chosen from the uniform distribution on $B(n,k)$, we want

$$\binom{n}k^{-1}\sum_{b\in B(n,k)}f(b)\;,$$

which isn’t hard to compute.

For any $i\in[n-1]$ there are $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$ strings $b=b_1b_2\ldots b_n\in B(n,k)$ such that $b_i=b_{i+1}=1$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{b\in B(n,k)}f(b)&=\sum_{i\in[n-1]}|\{b\in B(n,k):b_i=b_{i+1}=1\}|\\
&=\sum_{i\in[n-1]}\binom{n-2}{k-2}\\
&=(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and hence

$$\binom{n}k^{-1}\sum_{b\in B(n,k)}f(b)=\frac{k!(n-k)!}{n!}\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!}=\frac{k(k-1)}n\;.$$

If we want the actual distribution of $f(b)$, i.e.,

$$|\{b\in B(n,k):f(b)=m\}|$$

for each $m\in\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$, we have to work harder.

Suppose that $b\in B(n,k)$ has $\ell$ maximal blocks of ones. Each $1$ in a block except the first is the second $1$ of an adjacent pair, so $f(b)=k-\ell$, and $|\{b\in B(n,k):f(b)=m\}|$ is the number of $b\in B(n,k)$ having $k-m$ blocks of ones.

There are $\binom{k-1}{\ell-1}$ ways to divide $k$ ones into $\ell$ non-empty blocks. We now put a $0$ in each of the $\ell-1$ spaces between adjacent blocks of ones; that leaves $n-k-\ell+1$ zeroes to be distributed at will amongst the $\ell+1$ slots before the first block of ones, between adjacent blocks of ones, and after the last block of ones. This can be done in

$$\binom{(n-k-\ell+1)+(\ell+1)-1}{(n-k-\ell+1)-1}=\binom{n-k+1}{n-k-\ell+1}=\binom{n-k+1}\ell$$

ways, so there are

$$\binom{k-1}{\ell-1}\binom{n-k+1}\ell$$

strings in $B(n,k)$ with $\ell$ blocks of ones, and

$$\begin{align*}
|\{b\in B(n,k):f(b)=m\}|&=\binom{k-1}{k-m-1}\binom{n-k+1}{k-m}\\
&=\binom{k-1}m\binom{n-k+1}{k-m}\;.
\end{align*}$$

As a quick sanity check note that

$$\sum_m\binom{k-1}m\binom{n-k+1}{k-m}=\binom{n}k\;,$$

as it should.

The probability of choosing a word $b$ such that $f(b)=m$ is therefore

$$\binom{n}k^{-1}\binom{k-1}m\binom{n-k+1}{k-m}\;.$$

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the complete coefficient extraction. I was able to confirm it using the generating function, consult my modified answer. (+1).

Comment: @Marko: It’s always reassuring when we get the same answer! (I’d already upvoted yours, but it’s even better now.)

Comment: I have added some additional material concerning the variance where I hope I have not introduced any mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much for both of your answers. They are very clear and very instructive.

Comment: @Salsifis: You're very welcome.

Comment: Last question: are we surprised that the law of probability is the hypergeometric distribution?

Comment: @Salsifis: I’ve done very little with probability, so I really don’t have any feel for this. It’s not the typical hypergeometric situation, since the draws define the set of possible successes as well as the set of actual successes, but I guess that I’m not terribly surprised that the uniform distribution of the draws keeps the two sets independent.